# AWS Java SDK Call by Profile

Tags: aws-java-sdk

We have a multi account AWS setup. Each account is responsible for a different lane of development (DEV, QA, Production).

We also use ADFS to connect to authenticate for those different lanes.

I will make the following aws cli call to setup the credentials

```
aws-adfs login --profile=master --adfs-host=adfs.whatever.com --no-ssl-verification
```

The resulting credentials file will look like the following

```
[master]
aws_access_key_id = key_id
aws_secret_access_key = access_key
aws_session_token = session_token
aws_security_token = security_token
```

The other lanes are identified as profiles in the config file

```
[default]

[profile master]
region = us-west-2
output = text
adfs_config.ssl_verification = False
adfs_config.role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/AD_DeveloperRole
adfs_config.adfs_host = adfs.whatever.com
adfs_config.adfs_user = me@whatever.com
adfs_config.session_duration = 3600

[profile development]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::YYYYYYY:role/DeveloperRole
source_profile = master
region = us-west-2
output = json
adfs_config.ssl_verification = False
adfs_config.role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/AD_DeveloperRole
adfs_config.adfs_host = adfs.whatever.com
adfs_config.adfs_user = me@whatever.com
adfs_config.session_duration = 3600
```

Using the aws cli, I can access those other lanes by their profile. Here is an example

```
aws --profile=development ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /SOME_PARAMETER
```

However, I want to do this in code. Here is how I have it replicated using the AWS-JAVA-SDK

```
String region = new AwsProfileRegionProvider("profile development").getRegion();
CsmConfigurationProvider csmConfig = new ProfileCsmConfigurationProvider("profile development");
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("master");

AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssm = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard()
.withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
.withRegion(region)
.withClientSideMonitoringConfigurationProvider(csmConfig)
.build();

GetParametersByPathRequest request = new GetParametersByPathRequest();
request.setPath("/SOME_PARAMETER");
GetParametersByPathResult result = ssm.getParametersByPath(request);
```

But I get the error message

```
com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementException: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/AD_DeveloperRole/me@whatever.com is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParametersByPath on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXX:parameter/SOME_PARAMETER (Service: AWSSimpleSystemsManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: ***********)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1660) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1324) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1074) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.doInvoke(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:8126) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.invoke(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:8095) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.invoke(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:8084) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.executeGetParametersByPath(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:5021) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.getParametersByPath(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:4992) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.415.jar:na]
```

You will notice that it is trying to lookup the resource: *arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXX:parameter/SOME_PARAMETER* instead of the resource: *arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:YYYYYYY:parameter/SOME_PARAMETER*

If I update the ProfileCredentialsProvider with the profile "development" instead of "master" I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No AWS profile named 'development'
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.getCredentials(ProfilesConfigFile.java:158) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:161) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1186) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:776) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.doInvoke(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:8126) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.invoke(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:8095) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.invoke(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:8084) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.executeGetParametersByPath(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:5021) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.getParametersByPath(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:4992) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.415.jar:na]
```

What do I need to change in the Java code so that it will access the parameters stored in YYYYYYY instead of XXXXXXXXX?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here [aws-cli-role-assumption-profiles-are-incompatible-with-sdk](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/36689323-aws-cli-role-assumption-profiles-are-incompatible-with-sdk)

Apparently this is fixed in AWS Java SDK 2.x.

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer!